# See job graph size in Google Dataflow

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

I'm getting the following error message when attempting to run a pipeline:

> The job graph is too large. Please try again with a smaller job graph, or split your job into two or more smaller jobs.

According to the docs, the limit is 10 MB. However; I would like to know how big the graph actually is, to make debugging it easier.

Is there any way to see the size of the graph?

Comment: Can you use the `--dataflow_job_file gs://$BUCKET/out.json` flag (if using python) or `--dataflowJobFile gs://$BUCKET/out.json` ( for Java SDK), when deploying the pipeline? And tell me the file's size? It will output a .json representation of your pipeline  to a GCS bucket, which is a good estimate how of the size's request.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in the comment, use the `--dataflow_job_file` option. Note that there's no need to specify a gcs path, you can write it out locally. You can also pass the `--dry_run` option to avoid actually submitting the job.

Comment: Not that this won't give you the exact size, as the internal representation is a bit different, but it could be interesting to look at the resulting file and see which transforms/DoFns are bigger than expected.